# How does it remove duplicate object and subtract values from an object field with stream?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

according to a product list with these example values

```
new Product("A", new Stock(5));
new Product("B", new Stock(1));
new Product("A", new Stock(1));
```

I would like to filter the list of duplicate objects and if there is a duplicate object. I subtract the values ​​from it in the list.

```
//list after filter
Product A = 4 stock
        B = 1 stock
```

is it possible to do this with stream?

Comment: what if you have a stock of a bigger number than five? Would you do `5 - 1 - 9` or what?

Comment: can you show the `Stock` class ? and also what should happen if count becomes negative ?

Comment: if the subtraction is negative. could return zero

Comment: @FelipeMarcelo how do you determine if the subtraction is negative or not? What is there are negative values in the stock itself  `(1 - 5 - (-9))`? Moreover, where is your attempt? It would help clarify the question. Voting to close as this needs more focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) with mergeFunction, and in the merge function you can define the logic to subtract

```
    Collection<Product> result = products.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getName, Function.identity(), (p1, p2) -> {
                int count = p1.getStock().getValue() - p2.getStock().getValue();
                p1.getStock().setValue(count > 0 ? count : 0);
                return p1;
            })).values();
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend deadpool... in another scenario, if each time an object is repeated, subtract the stock by 1

then it would be,
int count = p1.getStock (). getValue () - 1?

Comment: Careful with this approach, as it modifies the original products' stock

Comment: That's correct @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner  and in case if he need he can also create new object

Comment: Since *subtraction is not associative*, this would lead to different results based on the order of the elements processed(e.g. `5-1=>4` and `1-5=>0`). (I would recommend @FelipeMarcelo to share the actual implementation they've tried or had with an imperative approach.)